# Different environment after EXEC command

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm preparing a SQL batch script like this

```
DECLARE @DateRateizzazionePerSA nvarchar(2000)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(3000)

SET @query = 'SELECT @DateRateizzazionePerSA = COALESCE(@DateRateizzazionePerSA+ '', '', '''') + a.RataStr FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RataStr =' 
            +' . . . '

EXEC(@query)
```

As you can see I have declared the varaible `DateRateizzazionePerSA` but this step is *invisible* to `EXEC` command, since I get an error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@DateRateizzazionePerSA".

What can I do? It seems like EXEC environment doesn't know external environment. Isnt'it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using variable value in string when executing EXEC in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052749/using-variable-value-in-string-when-executing-exec-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp_executeSQL` can be used to share data between the scopes;

```
DECLARE @DateRateizzazionePerSA nvarchar(2000) = 'Foo'
DECLARE @query nvarchar(3000)

SET @query = 'SELECT @DateRateizzazionePerSA += ''Bar''' 

EXEC sp_executeSQL @query,   
    N'@DateRateizzazionePerSA nvarchar(2000) OUTPUT',
    @DateRateizzazionePerSA OUTPUT

SELECT @DateRateizzazionePerSA

 == 'FooBar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape out of your text string to pass the variable into the query. 'SELECT '+@DateRateizzazionePerSA+

```
DECLARE @DateRateizzazionePerSA nvarchar(2000)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(3000)

SET @query = 'SELECT '+@DateRateizzazionePerSA+ '= COALESCE('+@DateRateizzazionePerSA+ '+ '', '', '''') + a.RataStr FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RataStr =' 
            +' . . . '

EXEC(@query)
```

As it was, the variable was not being evaluated, rather the string to be executed appeared to just have a new variable inside of it.

One thing I like to do to help troubleshoot dynamic sql is to change EXEC(@query) to PRINT(@query), which allows you to see how the query variable would be run.

Comment: No need to evaluate that variable. The evaluation process is next to the @query setting

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the problem.